# yfrog/twitpick libraries for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, twitpic, imageshack, yfrog

Any good silverlight libraries for accessing yfrog & twitpick rest apis or should I just create my own wrapper?

- [yfrog/imageshackapi API](http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/)
- [twitpic API](http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Twitpic does not allow access to their api by silverlight or flash application. (Unless if you are building trusted OOB app.) With that in mind I would not expect any silverlight libraries for twitpic to exist.

Quick search comes up empty on silverlight libraries for yfrog/imageshack. So I would venture the answer to your question is a no.